# Fan voltage - sticker vs specifications

Tags: voltage, fan

I am looking to replace the fan in my Marlec Solar iBoost as it is extremely noisy and causes insidious vibrations in the wall.

On the fan, the label shows as follows:

[image]

- Model: AV-F4020LB
- DC 5V

I checked the [specifications for that fan, it says that the AV-F4020LB is 12V.](https://ambeyond.en.made-in-china.com/product/wSCmsNoOiQhq/China-40X40X20mm-12V-24V-DC-Brushless-Cooler-Fan.html)

How can I tell if this is actually a 5V or 12V fan?

Assuming it is 5V, I am thinking of [purchasing one of these as a replacement.](https://noctua.at/en/products/fan/nf-a4x20-5v)

Do you foresee any issues with this?

Comment: I assume that if you had a multimeter then you would have checked the voltage already. If you had a 12 V fan with the correct connector, you could try that and see if it fails to start or rotates too slowly, indicating a 5 V supply.

Comment: Noctua's are good fans. About fans, be aware that "sleeved" wear out quicker than "ball bearing", and the faster the RPMs, the more noise it will make.  It's possible to get a slow-spinning fan which is very quiet, but then it won't move much air...

Comment: Marlec have a [Troubleshoot My Solar iBoost](https://www.marlec.co.uk/troubleshootmysolariboost/) page which has a section "My Solar iBoost fan is noisy" - it suggests checking for the presence of a rubber stop - have you read that part?

Comment: Thanks for the Marlec link - I have checked that and they've even sent me a replacement fan (with the same label), but that has made no difference to the noise levels.

Comment: Just measured and it definitely seems to be 5V across those two pins. That would mean the model number is correct (and complete), but both the voltage and current are wrong!

Comment: Does that mean that the fan I originally specified as an alternative /would/ work, or wouldn't?

Comment: @nitsuanomis If there's 5 V across the black and red wires going to the fan, it is *very* likely that it needs a 5 V fan, and the 5 V Noctua fan you linked to will work. The only possible snag after that is the physical compabitibility: judicious use of a file or some rubbery padding should take care of that. But, at the price of Noctua fans, I'm not promising anything ;)

Comment: Absolutely won't hold you to it, but I certainly do appreciate the advice! Thanks @AndrewMorton (and, in fact, everyone) for the rapid and helpful responses!

Answer (score 4):

The "specifications" you link to cut the model number short.  Yours is an "AV-F4020LB" while the linked item is an "AV-F4020."

Even the number on the fan is incomplete.

[This site](https://m.alibaba.com/product/60169388288/dc-brushless-5v-12v-micro-ventilator.html) gives longer versions of the model number.

[image]

There are two "LB" versions mentioned.  One ("LB") for 12V, the other is the "LB05" rated for 5V.

I'd be more inclined to trust what is on the fan than some vague specifications that aren't even from the manufacturer.

I'd also tend to measure the power supply to be sure. Use a voltmeter and measure from the red wire to the black wire.

Comment: It doesn't help that the current rating on the fan (0.07 A) corresponds to the current rating for the 12 V fan on the spec sheet while the current rating on the spec sheet for the 5 V fan is 0.14 A.

Comment: ... maybe, then, the model number is correct and the current is correct, but the voltage is wrong?

More likely, perhaps, than the voltage being correct, but the model number being incomplete and the current being wrong?

Only way to know for sure would be the voltmeter, right?

Comment: @nitsuanomis:  The sure way is to measure the supply voltage.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure I'm 100% comfortable sticking probes into live devices, but at 12V (max) it should be OK!

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 V, 12 V or even 24 V versions of AV-F4020LB. Also it has to be the 3-pin version, not the 2-pin nor the PWM version (4-pin).

Best fit I've found is: Noctua NF-A4x20 5V
Amazon link: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B071W6JZV8

Answer (score 0):

For the curious. i ordered the noctua fan. it fits, albeit you may need to snap the small plastic cable hooks (or unsleeve the noctuas cables).
Fan performs slightly better than marlecs and its slightly quieter.  Its still very much audible, but has less of an annoying tone.